# Use a Regex to form delimited string for SQL Server

Tags: c#, wpf, regex

I have a SQL Server database (service-based) with a table (Contact). Instead of having multiple tables, I decided to have one delimited string called Emails. So how could I use a Regex and a delimiter to add on to the string.

Comment: You're doing this despite the advice of SO telling you the opposite? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300376/store-array-in-sql-server-2008 ... Why? You're just making it difficult for yourself.

Comment: I was just curious on how. I'm still probably going to use the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should consider to change your decision to have delimited values instead of an extra table. It may seem simpler at first, but as you have already noticed, it quickly gets painful to work with.

That said, there are some different ways to handle delimited values, but using a regular expression is hardly one of them.

For example:

```
if (value.Length == 0) {
   value = email;
} else {
   value = value + delimiter + email;
}
```

Or:

```
List<string> emails = new List(value.Split(new String[]{ delimiter }));
emails.Add(email);
value = String.Join(delimiter, emails.ToArray());
```